# SQL(query) error or missing database error

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sql-insert, delete-row

SQL(query) error or missing database. (no such table: TABLE_NAME (code 1): while compiling: `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE IDNO = idNo`)

When I call `insertData()`, the app crashes by showing following error:

```
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
 TABLE_NAME (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM  TABLE_NAME 
 WHERE IDNO = idNo
     #################################################################
     Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
     Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (no such table: TABLE_NAME (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM  TABLE_NAME  WHERE IDNO = idNo)
     #################################################################
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
 Method)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1073)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:638)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1722)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1661)
         at my.utar.phonesecurity.DatabaseHelper.getData(DatabaseHelper.java:91)
         at my.utar.phonesecurity.BaseProfilingActivity.checkDatabase(BaseProfilingActivity.java:266)
         at my.utar.phonesecurity.BaseProfilingActivity.onCreate(BaseProfilingActivity.java:116)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6977)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
```

please see what is the error in it. so that that it can work properly.

```
package my.utar.phonesecurity;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.File;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "screenGestures";
    Context context;
    String[] deleteString = {"ID", "USER", "LENGTH", "ABSOLUTELENGTH", "DURATION", "AVGSPEED", "STARTPRESSURE", "ENDPRESSURE", "AVGPRESSURE",
            "STARTSIZE", "ENDSIZE", "AVGSIZE", "STARTX", "STARTY", "ENDX", "ENDY", "DIRECTION", "AREA", "MOVETYPE", "USERID",
            "TRORTST", "CRATEDAT", "MOBILEMODELNO"};

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(IDNO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ID TEXT,USER TEXT, LENGTH TEXT, ABSOLUTELENGTH TEXT, " +
                "DURATION TEXT, AVGSPEED TEXT, STARTPRESSURE TEXT, ENDPRESSURE TEXT, AVGPRESSURE TEXT, STARTSIZE TEXT, ENDSIZE TEXT, " +
                " AVGSIZE TEXT, STARTX TEXT, STARTY TEXT, ENDX TEXT, ENDY TEXT,DIRECTION TEXT, AREA TEXT, MOVETYPE TEXT, USERID TEXT ," +
                "TRORTST TEXT , CRATEDAT TEXT ,MOBILEMODELNO TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public boolean insertData(String id, String user, String length, String absoluteLength, String duration, String avgSpeed,
                              String startPressure, String endPressure, String avgPressure, String startSize, String endSize,
                              String avgSize, String startX, String startY, String endX, String endY, String direction,
                              String area, String moveType, String userId, String trOrTst, String cratedAt, String mobileModelNo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("ID", id);
        contentValues.put("USER", user);
        contentValues.put("LENGTH", length);
        contentValues.put("ABSOLUTELENGTH", absoluteLength);
        contentValues.put("DURATION", duration);`4`
        contentValues.put("AVGSPEED", avgSpeed);
        contentValues.put("STARTPRESSURE", startPressure);
        contentValues.put("ENDPRESSURE", endPressure);
        contentValues.put("AVGPRESSURE", avgPressure);
        contentValues.put("STARTSIZE", startSize);
        contentValues.put("ENDSIZE", endSize);
        contentValues.put("AVGSIZE", avgSize);
        contentValues.put("STARTX", startX);
        contentValues.put("STARTY", startY);
        contentValues.put("ENDX", endX);
        contentValues.put("ENDY", endY);
        contentValues.put("DIRECTION", direction);
        contentValues.put("AREA", area);
        contentValues.put("MOVETYPE", moveType);
        contentValues.put("USERID", userId);
        contentValues.put("TRORTST", trOrTst);
        contentValues.put("CREATEDAT", cratedAt);
        contentValues.put("MOBILEMODEL", mobileModelNo);

        if (db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int deleteData(int idNo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "IDNO = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(idNo)});
        /*if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }*/
    }

    public Cursor getData(int idNo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = " SELECT * FROM  TABLE_NAME  WHERE IDNO = idNo";
        /*String query = "SELECT *  FROM " + TABLE_NAME;*/
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public long getSize() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int size = (int) db.getPageSize();
        long sizee = new File(db.getPath()).length();
        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should actually be `SELECT * FROM screenGestures ...`

Answer (score 2):

In this line:
`String query = " SELECT * FROM  TABLE_NAME  WHERE IDNO = idNo";`

You're querying for a table called TABLE_NAME, it looks like you actually wanted to query the table whose name is contained in the variable TABLE_NAME so it should be something like:

`String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE IDNO = " + idNo;`

Also read up on SQL injection vulnerabilities and use parameterised queries to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is that the table named **TABLE_NAME** doesn't exist, that is because the TABLE_NAME has been enclosed in **`""`** and is taken literally as **TABLE_NAME** and has not been resolved to **screenGestures**.

To resolve this you could code `String query = " SELECT * FROM " +  TABLE_NAME + " WHERE IDNO = idNo";`

However, unless required, it is recommended to not use the **rawQuery** method but to use the convenience method **query**

As such you may wish to to use :-

```
public Cursor getData(int idNo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereclause = "IDNO=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(idNo)};
    return cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
}
```

- The conveniece methods had the following advantages :-

  - The underlying SQL is built on your behalf, thus reducing the chance for errors
  - The values (as passed via the 4th parameter (whereargs in the above)) are properly escaped(enclosed in quotes) and thus protected against SQL injection.
- Note the 3rd and 4th parameters are closely related, that is for every **?** (a placeholder for a passed value), the should be an element in the 4th parameter (a String array).
- The 2nd parameter, if null, equates to all columns (`SELECT * FROM .....`)
- The code above is in-principle code, it hasn't been tested or run. It may therefore contain simple errors.

You may wish to refer to [SQLiteDatabase - query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Note that there are 4 different **query** methods.